# Ajax Json won't allow double qoutes results

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, double-quotes

I got a problem on this code. json wont allow double quote results. ex. if i have a result (A sad "Story") json wont parse it.

```
$('.loader1').show();
$.ajax({
  url: "findBook.php?action=populatemyacademy&bookCatId="+parentCategoryId+"",
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    $('.loader1').hide();
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        $("#myAcademy").append('<div class="nameWrapper"><input name="checkMeM" type="checkbox" value="'+item.bookId+'"/><span title="'+item.bookName+'" class="checkBoxSpan">'+item.bookName+'</span></div>');
    });
}});
```

Here's how i generate json on my php script

```
 $sql = "SELECT academyBookId, title FROM academy_book WHERE academyBookCategoryId = $bookCatId AND academyId = $academyId";
    $qPopulateAcademy = mysql_query($sql, $dbConMain) or die(__LINE__.' '.$sql.' '.mysql_error());
    while($rPopulateAcademy = mysql_fetch_array($qPopulateAcademy)){
        $rows[] = array('bookId' => $rPopulateAcademy [0], 'bookName' => $rPopulateAcademy [1]);
    }
    $jsdecode = json_encode($rows);
    echo "{items:$jsdecode}";
```

Comment: @Ben: that's what im trying to figure out, does my question seems irrelevant?

Comment: It's not 100% clear but it's a worthy question. Someone counter upvoted you anyway.

Comment: I wish people would own up more to their downvotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the server renders it as " in your JSON document and this won't work work because json_encode uses "" to wrap, so you can do the following:

```
$jsdecode = json_encode($rows,JSON_HEX_APOS|JSON_HEX_QUOT)
```

which will replace the apostrophes and quotes with their hex codes.